# getting a pointer filled with input from stdin and using the pointer as input for a function

Tags: c

I have the following problem:
I need to read a string from stdin and must put it in an pointer.
Then I must use this pointer as input for a function that isn't in the main function.

This is what I tried so far

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
     
    #define LINE_LENGTH 50
     
    void print (char*text)
    {
        printf("%c", *text);
     
    }
     
    int main (void)
    { 
    char*keyboard;
    fgets(keyboard, LINE_LENGTH, stdin);   
     
     
    print (*keyboard);
     
     
    return 0;
    }
```

Thank you very much for reading this and thank you very much for answering.

Comment: You can't put strings in pointers.  Strings need to live in arrays.  You can then point a pointer at the array and have it point at the string.

Answer (score 1):

`char *keyboard;` is an uninitialized pointer. It reserves no memory for a string.

`printf("%c", *text);` would print the first character of a string. `%s` is the format specifier for printing entire strings, and expects a `char *`.

Try using an array, which automatically reserves memory on the stack. Arrays *decay* to pointers when passed to functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LINE_LENGTH 50

void print(char *text)
{
    printf("%s", text);
}

int main(void)
{
    char keyboard[LINE_LENGTH];

    if (fgets(keyboard, LINE_LENGTH, stdin))
        print(keyboard);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thinking more concretely about what is going on should help.

An object is a continuous set of bits in memory.  A variable is a name which is associated with an object.  A type is a more abstract idea which is associated with a variable, and can be "applied" to an object.

A pointer is a type which conveys the idea: "treat this object as a memory address".  A pointer can further convey a type that can be applied to the object *at that address*.

Memory can be allocated in different ways in different areas (statically, on the stack, or in some managed area, etc.).

So, when you declared `char*keyboard` in `main()`, you instructed the compiler to allocate an object *on the stack*, with the size of a memory address (e.g. 32 bits for x86 or 64 bits for x86_64), and associate it with the variable name `keyboard`.  The value stored in that object will then be treated *as an address* when it is accessed through `keyboard`.  If that address is dereferenced using `keyboard`, the (probably different) object at the address *stored in the object associated with `keyboard`* will be accessed, and treated as a `char`.

Here is a diagram to illustrate:

```
...
       keyboard
-------[0x1234]---------
...        \
...         \
...          v   
-------------[?]------
...
```

If the object associated with `keyboard` contains the value `0x1234`, then when it is treated as a `char *` and dereferenced, the character at location `0x1234` will be accessed, shown as `?`.

`fgets()` will *write* characters to memory, starting at the address provided as its first argument.  So it could store up to `LINE_LENGTH` characters, starting at the address stored in the object associated with `keyboard`, in your code.

**But no value has been assigned to `keyboard`**.

That means that the `fgets()` call could write characters to an undefined location in memory.

If you want to write up to `50` characters somewhere, you first must establish a safe place to write them.  You could do this by allocating 50 characters on the stack:

```
int main...
{
    char buffer[50];
    ...
```

or allocating static space for them:

```
char buffer[50];
...
int main...
{
    ...
```

Or by allocating some space in managed memory for them:

```
int main...
{
    char *buffer_ptr = malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
    if (!buffer_ptr) ...
    ...
    free(buffer_ptr);
```

You could then point `keyboard` to that storage by assigning the address of the first character to it:

```
    keyboard = &buffer[0];
    /* or */
    keyboard = buffer;

    /* or for the malloc() example case: */
    keyboard = buffer_ptr;
```

But in this case, you could probably just use `buffer` or `buffer_ptr` directly.

---

Thinking about it more concretely like this should hopefully clear up some confusion, but it might help to point out a couple more things:

Your `print()` function takes a `char *` argument, but your code passes a `char` to it.  This is because `keyboard`, which is a *pointer to a `char`*, has been dereferenced, yielding a `char`.

If the intent is to print only the first character of the memory which has been written to by the `fgets()` call, then either accessing that character and then passing it directly, or passing a pointer to it and dereferencing it
within `print()` would work, but not both.  If the intent is to print the entire string which has been read, then the pointer could be passed (without dereferencing it), but the `format` argument passed to `printf()` should contain `%s` for the string, and a *pointer* to that string should be passed to be converted by it.